# "ValueError" when writing the rows to CSV file

Tags: python, dictionary

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(result, fieldnames=Fnames)
for val in Fnames:
     for row in List:
          if str(row[1]) == str(val):
              dic = {str(val): row[2]}
              print dic.items()
              writer.writerows(dic)
```

I'm getting:

```
Error: ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: S, c, h, o, o, l
```

I am writing the dictionary values to the CSV file but I am getting the following error. I have tried different methods but with no success. What I have to do to write rows to the CSV?

Answer (score 1):

`Fnames` needs to be a `list` of field names to use. It looks like you have passed it the `string` "School" and it is iterating over each letter individually.

Check [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) for some documentation / examples.

Answer (score 1):

Error message states that your dictionary contains keys that don't have a corresponding entry in your `fieldnames` parameter. Assuming that these are just extra fields, you can ignore them by using the [`extrasaction` parameter during construction of your `DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) object:

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you're getting is because you're calling `writer.writerows` with a single dictionary as its argument. `writerows` expects to be given an iterable of dictionaries, not just one, and so it's misinterpreting things. It iterates over the dictionary (getting the keys) but expecting to be getting the inner dicts. When it iterates over those (to make sure the dictionaries have the expected keys), it is seeing the letters of the dictionary's key.

I'm not really sure what your logic is supposed to be though. Probably you shouldn't be iterating over `Fnames` at the top level, since every dictionary you write out needs to have every field in it (unless you specify a non-default value for the `extrasaction` parameter of `DictWriter`). Perhaps loop first over the `List` items, then over the `Fname` fields afterwards, adding a new key and value to the dictionary each time?